# jquery datatable scrollbar positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm having an issue with the jquery datatable. I'm trying to position the vertical scrollbar within the actual table i.e. within the borders of the tabke. The default behaviour is to have the scrollbar positioned next to the last column i.e. outside the table. I am using the bootstrap css for my table.

Code is here http://live.datatables.net/fopilode/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have manages to find a solution to this. I've added a border to to actual table wrapper like so :

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

JSbin for the solution is here : http://live.datatables.net/fopilode/17/edit

I've also managed the rounded edges. 2 New issues have now presented themselves :
1) Using the table-bordered class from bootstrap gives a double border on the left side. I've been trying top play around with css to remove the outer border of the table but still keep the inner borders for the td's of the table.

2) With vertical scrolling turned on the column headers seem to not line up perfectly with the rows in different browsers. I've tried the overflow no-wrap fix but this doesn't not appear to be working.

Any assistance with the above two issues will be appreciated.